# Wildlfy 8 : Runtime final Server has encountered an error

Tags: eclipse, jboss, wildfly-8

Any idea how to solve this issue? The following message occurs in eclipse when I attempt to start the server or publish a war to the server from eclipse:

> Error renaming
>   C:\runtimes\wildfly-8.0.0.Final\standalone\tmp\tmp1872668876413334227.MF
>   to
>   C:\runtimes\wildfly-8.0.0.Final\standalone\deployments\ContentStore.war\META-INF\MANIFEST.MF.

This may be caused by your server's temporary deploy directory being on a different filesystem than the final destination, but in my case the deploy directory is NOT on a different filesystem.

You may adjust these settings in the server editor.

Comment: @jan.supol , the deploy directory is not  on a different filesystem. Anything else to offer ?

Comment: @jan.supol, happens whenever I try to start my server or publish a war to ther server.

Comment: @jan.supol yes it is.

Comment: It looks like a permissions issue. Make sure the user starting the server has write permissions to the directories.